# Calling a web service from my chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a small chrome extension that should report back to my web service which url the browser is visiting. Any idea on how to send this back to my service? I tried a standard JQuery $.get method but that fails due to cross domain issues.

Are there any smarter ways than doing this? og does anyone have a sample that works

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/xhr.html#requesting-permission

Answer (score 4):

Your `JQuery $.get` fails because you have to explicitly tell Chrome which sites your application can communicate with.

1. Open up your `manifest.json` file.
2. Add sites into the `permissions` array. See the [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).

If you wanted to allow communication to all sites - you can add `"http://*/*", "https://*/*"`.

Also - if you are publishing to the Chrome Web Store - anyone who downloads your application will be told which permissions your application is granted.

Sources: [Declare Permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html), [Match Patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)